# How do I save mqtt data that I receive in python output on a text?

Tags: python

I am setting up to receive MQTT data from a subscribed topic on Python and I want to save the data in a text file.

My code is as follows:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as paho
import time
import sys
import datetime
import time
broker='192.168.1.3'  #host name
topic="/gw/ac233fc04e45/status"
     
def on_message(client, userdata, message):
print("received data is :")  
print(str(message.payload.decode("utf-8")) ) #printing Received message
print("")
 
client= paho.Client("user") #create client object 
client.on_message=on_message

print("connecting to broker host",broker)
client.connect(broker)#connection establishment with broker
print("subscribing begins here")    
client.subscribe(topic)#subscribe topic test

while 1:
 client.loop_start() #contineously checking for message
```

the output of the program is as follows:

received data is :
[{"timestamp":"2021-04-16T14:16:38Z","type":"Gateway","mac":"AC233FC04E45","gatewayFree":97,"gatewayLoad":0.15},{"timestamp":"2021-04-16T14:16:38Z","type":"Unknown","mac":"AC233FA27B5B","bleName":"","rssi":-34,"rawData":""},{"timestamp":"2021-04-16T14:16:39Z","type":"Unknown","mac":"AC233FA27B6A","bleName":"","rssi":-31,"rawData":""},{"timestamp":"2021-04-16T14:16:38Z","type":"Unknown","mac":"AC233FA28A31","bleName":"","rssi":-42,"rawData":""},{"timestamp":"2021-04-16T14:16:39Z","type":"iBeacon","mac":"AC233FA28A32","bleName":"","ibeaconUuid":"E2C56DB5DFFB48D2B060D0F5A71096E0","ibeaconMajor":0,"ibeaconMinor":0,"rssi":-74,"ibeaconTxPower":-59,"battery":0}]

I need to save time, mac addresses and rssi values to a text file.

Can someone please help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import json

def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    d = json.loads(message.payload.decode("utf-8"))
    with open("file.txt", "a+") as file:
        file.write("%s,%s,%s" %(d["timestamp"], d["mac"], d["rssi"]))
```